# SQL Server manager alternative

Tags: windows, database, sql-server

I am currently using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), which is way too heavy. I used to work with a different manager to connect to an Oracle database, but I don't recall the name. It was lightweight and allowed to edit values on the results grid. I don't need more than that, but the database is not on my local machine, if that is some sort of drawback.

If possible, I'd like for the tool to be free.

Have you got a recommendation for me?

I use Windows as the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/). It is light weight and it allows to edit the value and you would be able to connect to Oracle or SQLServer. It is available for free with limited features.